# JavaFX Enter por TAB

Tags: javafx

Alguém sabe como alterar o foco com a tecla enter ao invés de tab utilizando JavaFX. 
Já pesquisei um monte e não acho nada sobre. Somente em Java.

Por favor alguém já conseguiu fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer assim:

```
textfield1.setOnKeyPressed( (keyEvent) -> {  
    if(keyEvent.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER)
        textfield2.requestFocus();  
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Oi, pode usar este metodo, tem que passar uma lista de TextField do formulario, com o ordem em que vc deseja q aconteça o focus .

```
public void setNextFocus(TextField... texFiels) {

    for (TextField txt : texFiels) {
        txt.setOnAction(event -> {
            if (txt.getSkin() instanceof BehaviorSkinBase)
                ((BehaviorSkinBase) txt.getSkin()).getBehavior().traverseNext();

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigada mas já havia conseguindo usando a classe Robot             
`if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                try {
                    Robot avanca = new Robot();
                    avanca.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
            }`